# how to execute sql script using azure devops pipeline

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have SQL script which I want to execute using azure DevOps pipeline

I found multiple tasks for SQL but can not find any required task where I can pass sql server , database name and login details. Is there any task available for this ?

If there is not any task available and only way to execute is powershell script any sample available script for this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to execute sql scripts. Example:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "$(scriptfilepath)" -ServerInstance $(sqlserver) -Database $(dbname) -Username "$(username)" -Password "$(pwd)" -QueryTimeout 36000 -Verbose
```

Add custom variables (scriptfilepath, sqlserver, ...) and set values to them.

1. [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)
2. [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)
3. [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

Comment: How to run multiple sql files using the above script ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Invoke-Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) command like this

```
$SQLServer = "TestServerOne"
$db3 = "TestDB3"
$qcd = "PRINT 'This is output'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $db3 -Query $qcd -Username "User" -Password "Password" -Verbose
```

Make sure SqlServer module is installed. It works also with [Powershell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-manage-powershell-core?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can also try to use [Run SQL Server Scripts Task extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ggarbuglia.runsqlserverscripts-task)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this in Azure Release Pipeline (classic), you can use the '
**Azure SQL Database deployment**
' block which uses `Invoke-Sqlcmd` under the hood.

[image]

With that, you can configure it to execute an SQL script on a given database under one or your subscriptions or service connections.

[image]

Comment: how can we run multiple .sql files in one task?

Comment: @Schatak I don't know a proper way but if there's only a few I'll just duplicate the task. If you have so many of them, I'd say you do a file merge to create a single file during your build steps. Any text file merging technique would be fine for SQL too, but I haven't done this on a pipeline, so I don't really know what is available.

Comment: Does this also works if the SQL servicer is in private vnet in other subscription and no public endpoint?