# Execute/Deploy SQL script to sql server through Devops. what are possible options?

Tags: sql, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am new to Devops.
I want to Execute/Deploy SQL script to sql server through Devops(CI-CD). I would like to know what are the  possible options to achieve this and which is the preferable one Security wise and performance wise ???

My SQLscript will mostly contains 4, 5 Insert/update Script or 1 Procedure or function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to execute sql script using azure devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885558/how-to-execute-sql-script-using-azure-devops-pipeline)

Comment: No. it is taking about sql scripts. we need to go for DACPAC

Comment: @priyankagharat, updated my answer. please refer to that

Comment: Thank you @VenkataramanR for reply.....
I have .PS1 file which contains Insert scripts and Rest stuff to deploy other things(other than SQL)

Is it possible to read  those specific SQL scripts(mentioned below) from .PS1 using "inlinescript". How???(what will be inlinescript?)
Could you please help me in this


And when to prefer DACPAC Script,sqlscript or Inlinescript...

Example:

<#

DEV

Script 1
INSERT INTO Table1(.......) 
VALUES (.........)

Script 2
INSERT INTO Table1(.......) 
VALUES (.........)

Script 3
INSERT INTO Table1(.......) 
VALUES (.........)

#>

Comment: these insert scripts will be part of pre-deployment script. no need to have this as separate .ps1 file. Also, I would suggest you to raise separate question on this. Adding more information to same question and updating answer, will lead to confusion for future readers of this question

Comment: @priyankagharat What was the solution to your problem posted here? I am facing the similar

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is best practice to deploy the SQL server database code as DACPAC in DevOps in CI/CD manner.

[Read more Azure pipelines for SQL deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

You can refer to the blog posts, which provide step by step for the same:

- [DACPAC Deployment part 1](https://www.gatevnotes.com/continuous-deployment-sql-server-data-tools-project-template/)
- [DACPAC Deployment part 2](https://www.gatevnotes.com/continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-of-ssdt-projects-creating-azure-devops-pipelines/)