# How can I run SQL scripts which are there in Azure synapse analytics workspace using azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, sql-scripts, azure-synapse-analytics

I tried few steps:

1. Connected to azure cloud using service connection ( based on service principal), SPN has contributor level access at scope subscription and rg
2. Authenticated to Azure synapse analytics workspace using Get-AzSynapseWorkspace -Name $workspaceName
3. Get list of sql scripts using $scripts = Get-AzSynapseSqlScript -workspaceName $workspaceName
4. Now I am unable to find the command which can run the sql file in $scripts.

Note: Built-in SQL pool is there i.e. server less

I tried below command:

az synapse sql-script invoke `--resource-group $resourceGroupName`
--workspace-name $workspaceName `--name $scriptName`
--output table

I am unable to find correct command for my use-case

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell scripts to run scripts that are in serverless pools, [invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-2-invoke-commands-in-a-script-file-and-save-the-output-in-a-text-file) with PowerShell. Use the command below to run the script:

```
$scriptfilepath = <scriptfilePath>
$Server = "<serverName>"
$database = "<dbName>"
$username = "<userName>"
$password = "<password>"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "$(scriptfilepath)" -ServerInstance $(server) -Database $(database) -Username "$(username)" -Password "$(password)" -QueryTimeout 36000 -Verbose
```

For more information, you can refer to the links below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1120910/run-sql-scripts-stored-in-synapse-dev-instance-on
- [sql server - how to execute sql script using azure devops pipeline - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885558/how-to-execute-sql-script-using-azure-devops-pipeline)

Comment: In my case, I have server less SQL pool. How would above suggestion work, in such case?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1120910/run-sql-scripts-stored-in-synapse-dev-instance-on) once?

Comment: I checked it, but unable to create dacpac from .json version of sql script (due to azure devops repo). Could you help on that